# How can I remove this elements?

Tags: jquery

I have this codes:

```
<tr error_name="" class=" listing-row-even">
    <td style="text-align: right;" class="primary-cell">1</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;" dir="ltr" nowrap>
        <tt>modernqom.ir</tt>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;" dir="ltr" nowrap>2013-11-17 05:56:03</td>
</tr>
```

I wanna to remove all  nodes without the  node
How i can remove

I try this but not work:

```
$(".primary-cell").not('td:only-child').remove();
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove all `<td>` nodes and leave only the child `<tt>` node, or are you trying to remove all `<td>` nodes without the `<tt>` node? You probably should re-word the question to clarify what you are trying to do. (Note: as stated previously you need the `<tr>`/`<td>` nodes within the `<table>` to keep the structure valid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to have the `td` and `tr` elements to keep a valid html structure

```
$('tr td').not(':has(tt)').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P5cpS/)